# 503 error on SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Service

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, http-status-code-503

We are currently using SSRS 2008 R2 and have been for several years. We have a group who are writing/using large reports that are taking at times 400k ms to run. The reports are at times being exported to excel. Recently we are beginning to see 503 errors and the SSRS is being shut off or restarted.  How can I try and trap what exactly the issue could be and could this all be an IIS issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try https://dba.stackexchange.com/

In SQL Management Studio, the Object Explorer `Connect` button is a drop down -- one of the server types is `Report Server`

Connect to your instance of SSRS and

1. Check the `Execution` page for the report run time limit.
2. Check the `Logging` page and be sure logging is enabled

Then on the file system of your SSRS instance, look for the log files folder, at a path something like

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles`

but you have to adjust the path for the SQL x32 or x64 and Version (10== SQL2008)

(For example, for x64 SQL 2012, it is: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles`)

Your actual failure should be in this log!